# Input Source Capacitance Value for GBW Calculation

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitance, photodiode, gain-bandwidth-product

For the calculation of GBW product for a photodiode:

[image]

Which diode capacitance value do I use for the input source capacitance (Cs)? I am having trouble understanding the difference between the 400pF vs 1.2nF.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Which diode capacitance value do I use for the input source capacitance (Cs)? I am having trouble understanding the difference between the 400pF vs 1.2nF.

The 400 pF capacitance is when the diode is biased at 5 V. 1200 pF is for zero bias on the diode.

What voltage do you intend to bias the diode at?

Maybe the difference in capacitance, and thus speed of otherwise equivalent circuits, would prompt you to choose a bias level.

Comment: "Maybe the difference in capacitance, and thus speed of otherwise equivalent circuits, would prompt you to choose a bias level." Could you elaborate more on this?

Comment: I applied no DC bias to the system, so I would use the 1200pF value. Is there a reason I must apply a bias level if I am just reading light levels from a photodiode?

Comment: @Kevin Biasing a photodiode makes it faster and much more linear but increases dark current. Except at very low light levels, usually a bias is preferred but it will depend on what you're doing.

Comment: @user1850479 Why is a bias preferred?

Comment: @Kevin It's faster and much more linear.